# Form Hide not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Something strange, This form is opened from another from but I want the form to close and return to the initial form if user input are missing. This is not happening, WHY ?

```
Try
        Dim din As Int32 = (Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedValue)

        Dim dt As String = Form1.Label1.Text
        Dim dt2 As String = Form1.Label2.Text
        If din = Nothing Or dt = Nothing Or dt2 = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Staff and Date Range", "Error!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()

        Else
            ' MsgBox(din & "/" & dt & "/" & dt2)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = getTable(din, DateTime.Parse(dt), DateTime.Parse(dt2))
            DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
            Me.Text = "Selected Staff: " & CStr(Form1.ComboBox1.Text)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Did You set a breakpoint in the code? Mind: An empty string is not equal to Nothing. Apart from that: Do not let the forms call one another. Use a class that holds references to both.

Comment: it is best practice to create an instance of the forms rather than direct singleton access. it will also solve a lot of headaches that you will get into and I can already see it happening (i.e changing variables from one form to another then expect it to be set to defaults afterwards). Also show the code on how you are showing this form

Comment: ok @ahmed-ilyas i'd fix that. thanks

Comment: Use the `OpenDialog` instead of `show` to keep the same thread and return to the previous on form close.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `Text` property of `Labels`

```
Dim din As Int32 = (Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
Dim dt As String = Form1.Label1.Text
Dim dt2 As String = Form1.Label2.Text
If din = Nothing Or dt = Nothing Or dt2 = Nothing Then
```

but they will never be `Nothing`. If you try to set `Nothing` to a `Text` property of a `Control`, it will use an empty string instead. I think that is your main problem.

Also, you convert the `SelectedValue` property to `Integer` and check it for `Nothing`. Note that this will be `true` if the `SelectedValue` is `0`, since it's the default value of `Integer`.

You should use a debugger and step through your code to be able to solve such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I finally figured out that I am better off checking the user selections in the original form rather than checking for null values in the called up form.

I appreciate all your input. Thanks.